# jQuery tagging plug-in, how to get user input value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using this tagging plug-in: http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/

One thing that is not covered in the docs is how to get currently **typed-in** value. I need this in order to build the querystring for a custom autocompleter.

```
$('#tags').tagsInput({    
  autocomplete_url:'http://myserver.com/api/autocomplete?term='(??????),
  autocomplete:{selectFirst:true,width:'100px',autoFill:true}
});
```

Comment: add a keystroke listener?

Comment: Since this plug-in already supports autocompleter it should somehow be able to do this internally somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking at the tagging plug-in for the solution I decided to look at the [Autocompleter](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) itself and extract the value from there.

```
var tags = [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ];
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      }
});
```

From here I noticed the `request.term` variable, which I could then grab for my own Ajax call parameter.